# Reading files from S3 using HadoopInputFile yields FileNotFoundException

Tags: scala, hadoop, amazon-s3, parquet

I am trying to read parquet files from directory at S3

```
val bucketKey = "s3a://foo/direcoty_to_retrieve/"
val conf: Configuration = new Configuration()
conf.setBoolean(AvroReadSupport.AVRO_COMPATIBILITY, true)
val inputFile = HadoopInputFile.fromPath(new Path(bucketKey), conf)
val reader: ParquetReader[GenericRecord] =  AvroParquetReader.builder[GenericRecord](inputFile).withConf(conf).build()
```

however I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory: s3a://foo/direcoty_to_retrieve
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.s3GetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:3356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.innerGetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:3185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:3053)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopInputFile.fromPath(HadoopInputFile.java:39)
```

EDIT:
When I use the `AvroParquetReader.builder` with `filePath` e.g :

```
val reader: ParquetReader[GenericRecord] =  AvroParquetReader.builder[GenericRecord](new Path(bucketKey)).withConf(conf).build()
```

it works, however this option is deprecated and I rather not use it.
on local directory it works. my env variables for `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` are set correctly. what can be the problem ?

Comment: Does that directory or file actually exist?

Comment: Is there a particular reason not to use the S3 Java SDK rather than Hadoop?

Comment: @m_vemuri yes for sure

Comment: @OneCricketeer the reason that i am using hadoop is that I am working with parquet files

Comment: Parquet can be read from S3 without directly using Hadoop SDK. For example, Spark/Flink/Beam local modes. Alternatively, I assume you've seen this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61126391/how-to-read-parquet-file-from-s3-without-spark-java#61215299

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with reading parquet file from Amazon S3 storage via [Alpakka Avro parquet](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/avroparquet.html) lib (which depends on `parquet-hadoop-1.10.1.jar`). After some debugging I found out the issue in `ParquetReader.build` method.

```
public ParquetReader<T> build() throws IOException {
  ParquetReadOptions options = optionsBuilder.build();

  if (path != null) {
    FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem(conf);
    FileStatus stat = fs.getFileStatus(path);

    if (stat.isFile()) {
      return new ParquetReader<>(
          Collections.singletonList((InputFile) HadoopInputFile.fromStatus(stat, conf)),
          options,
          getReadSupport());

    } else {
      List<InputFile> files = new ArrayList<>();
      for (FileStatus fileStatus : fs.listStatus(path, HiddenFileFilter.INSTANCE)) {
        files.add(HadoopInputFile.fromStatus(fileStatus, conf));
      }
      return new ParquetReader<T>(files, options, getReadSupport());
    }

  } else {
    return new ParquetReader<>(Collections.singletonList(file), options, getReadSupport());
  }
}
```

When `HadoopInputFile` is used as input, builder `path` property set to `null` and reader initiated in else block. As parquet file represented as a directory in filesystem this leads to `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

Solution for now will be to use deprecated method:

```
AvroParquetReader.builder[GenericRecord](new Path(bucketKey)).withConf(conf).build()
```